# Xcode: is there a way to disable iOS Camera using UIImagePicker?

Tags: iphone, xcode, function, camera

well, I guess the question says it all

I'm open to using Private API's, I'm trying to create an app which, if it detects a certain GPS: location the camera functions should self disable. . . .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** this solution doesn't use `UIImagePicker`.  I'm assuming you're referring to the built-in Camera.app, and just want some way to disable it.

If you are willing to jailbreak your device (which I read in your comments), then you should be able to do this.

First, you'll need to write an iOS **Launch Daemon**.  This is a background process (no UI) that simply runs all the time, and monitors location.  See [the blog for an example of how to write a launch daemon](http://chrisalvares.com/blog/7/creating-an-iphone-daemon-part-1/). This example even shows a daemon that monitors location, which is what you'll need.

Then, when your daemon detects that you're in the special location, you could just change the executable permissions on `/Applications/Camera.app/Camera`.  Make it not executable (`chmod 664` instead of `775`).

Invoke the `chmod` command from your app by making a system call:

```
system("chmod 664 /Applications/Camera.app/Camera");
```

Or, you could probably also use the `NSFileManager` APIs to modify the permissions attributes on the file.

Of course, you'll need to change permissions back when you leave the area (you might want to make the app conservative, so that if no location data is available, after a timer delay, you re-enable the Camera).

I believe the daemon tutorial I linked to above will setup your daemon to run as the root user (userid = 0), which is probably necessary to have permission to change the Camera executable permissions.  If not, post a reply, and I'll dig up more information.  I have multiple daemons running on my phone (that I wrote a while ago), and they do have root privileges, so I must have figured out how to do it :)

Also, as Owen said, **Location Services** might be turned off, or a location fix might be unavailable.  I'm not sure if this app is just for you, to remind you not to take pictures in a certain location, or if it needs to be secured against other users, who will try to defeat the protection.  If this is an issue for you, post some more information and we'll go from there ...

**Note**: I'm not sure if this also needs to *disable* the Camera if it's already running before you enter the no-pictures-zone.  If so, you could have your daemon also issue a `kill` command on the Camera process.

Comment: Note that this solution just disables the camera application, not the camera.  There are many applications that can use the camera.

Comment: @OwenHartnett, absolutely.  Like I said in the answer, there's other issues if the intent of this app (which wasn't clarified in the question) is to prevent potentially malicious users from circumventing this, because they can always just turn off location services.

Comment: @Nate, Hi Nate if you've created a daemon tool already, you may know I'm actually having a hard time finding the toolchain for xcode 4.3  = = = =any idea where I should look ?

Comment: @TaskinulHaque, I've never needed anything except for the Xcode that comes from Apple (version 4.3, or any other version), and then `ldid` to fake code sign the executable file.  In Xcode, I set the build settings to "Don't Code Sign", and then after building, I sign the executable with `ldid -S MyAppName`.  You can find ldid in a couple places, but right now, I'm using [the one that KennyTM pre-built for OS X and posted on his site here](http://code.google.com/p/networkpx/downloads/list)

Comment: Of course, signing with `ldid` requires a jailbroken phone for the bogus signature to be accepted, but by looking at your comments to Owen's answer, I assume you're ok with jailbreaking the device.   After code signing, I then use something like SSH to upload the app bundle to the device, and install it manually (outside of Xcode).

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you want to disable camera use when the iDevice is in a particular location.  I don't think you can, successfully.  Even if you could write an app that would disable the camera when it detects location inside a certain latitude, presumably by activating the camera yourself and not permitting it to be used, there's no guarantee that your app would even be running in the background.  Also, location services may be turned off and your app would not be aware of its location.  You'd also have to jailbreak the device to get around the sandboxing.  Right now there's no way to write a general purpose daemon in iOS, certainly not one that captures a hardware resource.  If I've misunderstood, you might want to elaborate more on what you intend to do.

Comment: you have the correct idea; lets look over whether the app is running or not, whether the gps is on, or the jailbreaking, maybe its not possible to disable the hardware, but is it possible to overlay the camera with a blank image for instance?

Comment: No. You can not do anything when your app is not running and there is no way to stop the user from closing it. (Without jailbreaking)

Comment: so it is impossible to overlay the camera with a black image, even if the device was jailbroken ?

Comment: I think you're getting to the point where you're deleting so much of the unique Apple iOS protection, you might as well just do it on Android.

Comment: i realize that now! I should have started on Android, but I've honestly come too far with iOS . . . .